# Membrr: Coupon being ignored

Tags: membrr, coupon-code

I am having trouble with getting the coupon to work properly. According to [the docs](http://www.membrr.com/docs) all I had to do was add a blank field with the name of coupon but it isn't working.

When I test with a real coupon code it still charges full price. I have tried testing with an incorrect coupon code. Both times the form doesn't throw any errors and charges full price.

I am using a testing gateway to submit the form with the coupon.

I can confirm:

- The name and id on the blank text field is correct.
- It is inside of the membrr form tag.
- The coupon was created correctly in OpenGateway.

Would love any insight to why the coupon is being ignored. We just need the coupon to work for now until we can migrate the client to a new addon.